# Modify datatype of a field in JSONB in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a JSONB column with JSON that looks like this:

> {"id" : "3", "username" : "abcdef"}

Is there way to update the JSON to :

> {"id" : 3, "username" : "abcdef"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the jsonb column using the [concatenate operator ||](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html), e.g.:

```
create table example(id int, js jsonb);
insert into example values
(1, '{"id": "3", "username": "abcdef"}');

update example
set js = js || jsonb_build_object('id', (js->>'id')::int)
returning *;

 id |               js                
----+---------------------------------
  1 | {"id": 3, "username": "abcdef"}
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select json_build_object('id',CAST(j->>'id' AS NUMERIC),'username',j->>'username')::jsonb  from (
    select '{"id" : "3", "username" : "abcdef"}' :: jsonb AS j
)t
```